# How can I make this update every 5 seconds?

Tags: php

I would like to know how I can make this

index.php

```
<?php
echo "Players Online: ".$Hypixel->players->online."/".$Hypixel->players->max."<br />";
?>
```

is being updated every 5 seconds

servers.php

```
<?php
    $Hypixel_json_infoquery = file_get_contents('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/mc.hypixel.net');
    $Hypixel = json_decode($Hypixel_json_infoquery);
?>
```

Comment: Probably you mean "how to make some element of downloaded page updating every 5 seconds"?  Please consider articulating clearly what ad where do you need to be updating, what have you tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: That'll be a good way to get yourself blocked from gameapis.net's API.

Answer (score -1):

PHP only updates on page load. It can be forced to do a meta refresh, but that would cause a full reload.

Your best bet is to write some JavaScript that does an Ajax request, and updates the page DOM. Something similar to this should work (in all browsers bar IE11):

```js
setInterval(function () {    
    fetch('https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/info/mc.hypixel.net')
        .then(function(response) {
            // update DOM here
        });
}, 5)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I understand this question isn't great (having 4 downvotes) but I believe this answers the question.